# Handle closing event for dynamically created form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program up and running that can read in data from a piece of hardware. My program has the ability to graph these incoming values at rates specified by the user. (Using a zedgraph control). When the user chooses to graph the values, a new form is dynamically created that contains the graph.

In practice, a user can have as many graphs as they want. My problem is I need to create an event handler for when those dynamically created forms (containing the graphs) are closed. I know for my main UI I can just use the designer tool and click the closed event to make a handler. However I'm not sure how to do this for a dynamically created form.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer isn't doing anything fancy.  You can see what it's doing in the .Designer.cs file.  Here's how you do it yourself:

```
myDynamicForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(your_handler_method);
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question: If I need to pass some object (other than the form that was closed) to the event handler, how would I declare that?

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't get to define the method signature of the event handler; that's determined by the `FormClosingEventHandler` delegate definition.  But you could store such an object as a member variable of the calling class and use it within the event handler.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Form's [`FormClosed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4). You can hook it up using code like so:

```
var form = new WhateverForm();
form.FormClosed += (sender, e) => DoStuffs(form);
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a handler to an event in code:

```
someObject.SomeEvent += SomeHandler;
```

`SomeHandler` can be a lambda expression, anonymous method, or an actual method name.